# How to read kafka consumer topic to pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka consumer topic which I need read from a server to store to dataframe

**My Code**

```
bootstrap_servers =  ['internal-systest-1.int:9092', 'internal-systest-2.int:9092']

logger.info('Preparing Consumer to listen...')
topicName = 'C01'

consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName, enable_auto_commit=False, consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
                        bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers, auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                        group_id=None, value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
                        api_version=(0,11,5))


logger.info('Preparing Message ...')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for message in consumer:
    print("%s key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.key, message.value))
    message = json.loads(json.dumps(message.value))
    json2 = pd.json_normalize(message)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(json2)
    df = df.append(df2)

logger.info('Dataframe loaded from Kafka Message ...')
```

Currently I am getting an empty dataframe as output

Is my code correct?

Comment: If `message.value` is a string/bytes, do not dumps it then loads it. You should already have json from the value deserializer in the consumer constructor., so you don't need to do anything with the value when you get it, except read it with pandas.. . But is there a specific reason not to use pyspark / koalas since getting dataframes from Kafka is already a feature of it?